# What's the best way to periodically reload an iframe with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I'm building a webpage using React which means I can't manipulate the DOM directly. I've tried reloading my iframe by updating the url state but that doesn't seem to reload the page. This is the state code I have tried.

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        this.setState({currentUrl:currentUrl});
    }.bind(this), 1000);
},
 getInitialState: function() {
    return {defaultUrl:this.props.graph.url, currentUrl:this.props.graph.url};
},
render() {
    // render the graph iframe
    return (
        <iframe src={this.state.currentUrl} id={this.props.graph.url} style={this.props.style} width={this.props.width} height={this.props.graph_height} />
    )
}
```

Comment: Using `forceUpdate` would force a re-render(): https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: I've tried that but it wasn't doing anything the iframe still didn't reload

Comment: Define "wasn't doing anything". A call to `forceUpdate`is guaranteed to invoke `render` in your component, which would necessarily repaint the `iframe`. Can you create a plunkr or codepen?

Comment: It wasn't forcing an update, maybe i'm using it wrong. I just replaced this.setState({currentUrl:currentUrl}); with this.forceUpdate()

Comment: codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ggPGPQ

Comment: That pen is working for me! If you put a `console.log('Rendering');` in the top of the `render()` function (before the `return`), you'll see that it does in fact re-render. Perhaps the content within the iframe itself isn't changing? But that would be outside of React.

Comment: That just tells you that the setInterval function is being called, not that the page is reloading. You can see what a reload should look like if you right click in the iframe and select "Reload Frame". If you do that you will see that the graphs update on reload

Comment: No, the fact render _is_ getting invoked by setInterval means the screen is repainting the DOM. React is working appropriately here.

Comment: But you can see clearly on the website that the iframe is not being re-loading because the graphs aren't updating. You can also see in the console when you look at the network request that it is not requesting the grafana page every 5 seconds as it should be. React may be "re-rendering" but it is not reloading my iframe which is what i wanted. Another user was able to solve my problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580557/how-to-use-forceupdate-correctly if you want to see how i wanted it to behave

Comment: I'm glad you got it working - it does seem a little hacky though. If you need to go as far as unmounting the entire iframe, I'd lastly suggest wrapping it in your own component, `KaitlynsIFrame`, which abstracts away that toggling behavior, but good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use forceUpdate() correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580557/how-to-use-forceupdate-correctly)

Answer (score 5):

Change key property for  component
for example:

```
this.state = {iframeKey: 0};

setInterval(() => this.setState(s => ({iframeKey: s.iframeKey + 1})), 1000);

<Iframe key={this.state.iframeKey} url={some url}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a use case for the [`ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) property if, as I assume, the contents of the iframe isn't under react control. Apply one to the iframe, then use the setInterval to refresh the iframe url.

The reason the iframe isn't updating when you set the URL in state is that the url hasn't changed(?) and react doesn't redraw when that's the case.

Comment: That's what i thought too so i kept adding "1" to the end of the url to see if it would update to an invalid website. The iframe never reloaded but when i opened the console i could see the src attribute updating so react is manipulating the element but the iframe isn't reloading.